# Creating form for end user using FormBuilder Plugin JSON

Tags: jquery, json, formbuilder

I am trying to integrate [Dobtco FormBuilder Plugin](https://github.com/dobtco) in my application.

Can any body guide me how can I create form "formbilder JSON" shown below for the end user where user can enter values and save those in DB:

```
{"fields": [
             {"field_type": "date", 
              "required": true, 
              "label": "datum", 
              "field_options": {}, 
              "cid": "c2"
             }
            ]
 }
```

I know there is "bootstrapData" option available in plugin but it only allows to edit the  form structure.